How to split single element of list and maintain order in list?
I have a list:
ll=['the big grey fox','want to chase a squirell', 'because they are friends']

I want to split the 2nd element, ll[1], into "want to chase" and " a squirell".
I want to end up with:
['the big grey fox','want to chase', ' a squirell', 'because they are friends']

Note that the first element needs to be always split so that the last 10 characters are a new element of the list, immediately after the first n-10 char of the element before, so that the order of joined text is not altered.
I currently use:
ll[:1],ll[1][:len(ll[1])-10], ll[1][-10:],ll[2:]

but is there a prettier way of doing this?

You can use:
ll[1:2] = ll[1][:-10], ll[1][-10:] 

to replace a second element with a split pair.
Sidenote: if you want the exact output as in your question, you need to split on index -11.
Sidenote2: ll[1][:len(ll[1])-10] is equivalent to ll[1][:-10]

You could also write ll[1:2] = (y:=ll[1])[:-10], y[-10:], if you find that more readable. (Probably not; this is an example where I think something like ll[1:2] = let y = ll[1] in y[:-10], y[-10:] would have worked better.)

@SuramuthuR 1. Yes, that's my first "sidenote". 2. That would remove the space which based on the example in the question, OP wants to preserve.
